# How to display information from an object while accessing address with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

how to do for when hitting an URL, example, localhost:8080/info, the application display in the browser the data of the object but **not** in JSON format, just show like this:

name: Roger
Last name: Silva
Age: 40

I tried this way, but I know it's not right, will I need an HTML page?

```
@GetMapping("/info")
public BwsInfoDto getInfo() {
   return person.getInfoPerson(); 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add `produces = {"text/plain"}` to `@GetMapping` and make `BwsInfoDto` return the data the way you want overriding `toString()`

Comment: no problem! you don't need to add [RESOLVED] to the question, just accept the answer. I've edited for you and fixed

Answer (score 0):

The goal of a rest service is to provide data in a compact format that can be used by other applications, which usually use JSON, HTML or XML as data formats.

I would suggest you write minimal client code to access your service and use the requested data. This way, you can do whatever you like with the data, also changing its format.

To summarize:

- Use JavaScript or any JavaScript library (like JQuery) to fetch data from your service in
- Render that data on a webpage using your preferred format